# Permissions to write into but not view a list?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, visual-web-part

I have a custom web part on my home page that is essentially a textbox and a button for submitting suggestions. 
The suggestions are written to a custom list named "Suggestions". 
Now, I would like for Users to be able to write but not view others' suggestions. 
What kind of permission tailoring am i looking at??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Item Level permissions.

Change read and edit access to only the ones created by the user.

Comment: This works better than what I had in mind! Thanks a bunch